# More Image from Library

Tags: ios, swift, picker

I'm writing a simple app and I'm not able to show more images from Photo Library in two separate `ImageView`.

Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageVie2: UIImageView!


    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    func noCamera(){
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera",message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",style:.Default,handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alertVC,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func photoFromLibrary(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        picker.allowsEditing = false //2
        picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary //3
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)//4
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    }


    //take a picture, check if we have a camera first.
    @IBAction func shootPhoto(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
            picker.allowsEditing = false
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
            presentViewController(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
        } else {
            noCamera()
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self  
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        myImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        myImageView.image = chosenImage 

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, nil, nil, nil);

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 


    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true,completion: nil)}
}
```

Comment: Hi,it may be because of allowsEditing=false,check once by commend that line

Comment: No, it isn't, but thank for help =)